# Database of inaccuracies in mainstream media

Tags: data-request, media

I am looking for a database of mistakes that appear in media.

For instance when a famous newspaper forgets a digit when giving a country's population, or mixes biographies of two persons with the same name.

Both professionally-edited repositories and community-edited repositories are OK. Preferably free access/download under an open reuse license.

Mostly for newspapers, but TV and radio are also OK. Preferably worldwide.
Low diffusion and fringe media is not needed, only mainstream media with large diffusion.
This is for verifiable mistakes, not for debated facts like whether Taiwan is part of China or not.

For each mistake:

- Original statement
- Reference showing it is a mistake
- Official retraction if available
- Media outlet
- Date
- Maybe tags like "persons", "countries", "history", "science"

Answer (score 2):

It's just a subset of "mainstream media", but you can use the [NYTimes API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2) to search for "Correction: ".

They also maintain a [page with recent corrections](http://www.nytimes.com/pages/corrections/index.html), which point to the amended article.

Their format looks like this, so it should be easy to find with the API.

[image]

---

You'll probably have to create the "database". This NYTimes data would plug into the data model and some fields you'd have to generate (i.e. tags)